# FTL quantum messages

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I read of a method for spies to carry quantum encrypted messages, that if the first one was caught and the message looked at, the home base spy copy message would turn to garbage. From that they would know he was caught. 
  I was thinking if we shot a message like that into outer space, and "someone" looked at it, we could tell if anybody out there.
  Or does this fail the FTL test?

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite like that. You can read (ie. measure a quantum property of) the message being received and know if somebody else has already read it. You can't find out instantly if somebody else is currently reading it without also reading it destroying the 'unread' property yourself.

So you can't instantaneously detect that it is currently being read by somebody else and use that as a way of transferring information faster than light.

We have done this test into space, or at least along a laser beam between the ground and a satelite